# Python Character Casing

Tags: python

From a given string I need output according to:

- If index position is even - upper case
- If index position is odd - lower case

What's wrong with the following code?

```
def Fun_Case(*args):
    n=0
    for x in (args):
        if n%2==0:
            print(x[n].upper())
        else:
            print(x[n].lower())
        n+=1

Fun_Case('python PRogrammING')
```

It's not iterating. It's just printing the first letter and exiting.

Comment: Do you understand what `*args` does?

Comment: Don't use `*args`... name it `my_string`. your goal is to reference a string since this is what you pass.

Comment: Furthermore you *index* over the characters. If you remove the asterisk, `args` is a single string, and then `x` is a character.

Comment: Within the loop, before your `if` insert:  `print(x)`, that should help.

Comment: just remove the *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's wrong with your code:

1. You're using *args which would expand the string you're passing into the function's arguments which is not what you want. I've replaced it with `arg`.
2. You're using `x[n]` instead of simply `x`. When you're looping through the string, you're going at it one character at a time. Therefore, simply `x` is sufficient.

---

```
In [6]: def Fun_Case(arg):
   ...:     for idx, x in enumerate(arg):
   ...:         if idx%2==0:
   ...:             print(x.upper(), end='')
   ...:         else:
   ...:             print(x.lower(), end='')
   ...:         
   ...: 
   ...: Fun_Case('python PRogrammING')
```

Output:

```
PyThOn pRoGrAmMiNg
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual question of "What's wrong with my code", only provides a solution

Comment: @Sayse, just added some explanation.

Comment: 1) What's wrong with adding *args.. using *args I can pass any number of arguments.. that is what I understood.
2) @Ashish 
a)why should we use enumerate
b)what does end = ' ' do in the print function.

Comment: That's true. But all you need is one argument in this function, namely the string that you're iterating over.

Comment: My *args doubt is clarified Ashish Thank You.
But can you help me understand why did you use enumerate?
also what does end = ' ' do in the print function

Comment: `enumerate` here basically does what you're doing with `n`, that is, track the index of the iteration. `print` would normally output a new line after execution. So to stop that we add `end=''`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the clarification Ashish